# Preview BitMap in ImageView from a Base64 string

Tags: android

I tried to store a `BitMap` in the database as `Base64` string, but somehow I just cant preview it in the `ImageView`. Here's the code:

Store Data:

```
Map params = new HashMap();
params.put("faasid", faasid);
params.put("title", data_title);
params.put("image", Base64.encodeToString(DbBitmapUtility.getBytes(bitmap),Base64.DEFAULT));

ImageDB db = new ImageDB();
db.create(params);
```

Retrieve Data:

```
List<ImageItem> data = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();

Map params = new HashMap();
params.put("faasid", faasid);

ImageDB db = new ImageDB();
List<Map> list = db.getList(params);

for(Map m : list){
    String title = m.get("title") != null ? m.get("title").toString() : "";
    String image = m.get("image") != null ? m.get("image").toString() : "";

    data.add(new ImageItem(faasid, title, image.getBytes()));
}

image_list.setAdapter(new ImageItemAdapter(activity,data));
LayoutParams layout = (LayoutParams) image_list.getLayoutParams();
layout.height = (320 * data.size());
image_list.setLayoutParams(layout);
```

**ImageItem.java**:

```
public class ImageItem {

    private String faasid, title;
    private byte[] image;

    public ImageItem(String faasid, String title, byte[] image){
        this.faasid = faasid;
        this.title = title;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getFaasId(){ return faasid; }
    public String getTitle(){ return title; }
    public Bitmap getImage(){ return DbBitmapUtility.getImage(image); }

}
```

**DbBitmapUtility.java**

```
public class DbBitmapUtility {

    // convert from bitmap to byte array
    public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

    // convert from byte array to bitmap
    public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    }

}
```

**ImageItemAdapter.java** (my custome ListView adapter)

```
public class ImageItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    Context ctx;
    List<ImageItem> data;

    public ImageItemAdapter(Activity activity, List<ImageItem> data){
        ctx = activity;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup vgroup) {
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_menu, null);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image_menu_view);
        TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image_menu_text);

        ImageItem item = data.get(pos);
        if(item != null){
            image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
            title.setText(item.getTitle());
        }

        return rowView;
    }

    public ImageItem getListItem(int pos){
        return data.get(pos);
    }
```

**I print the result of this code: `List list = db.getList(params);`, and there was data in it, but the problem is: The image wont appear in the `ImageView`.**

Comment: You did not show how you write it to the DB and read it from DB. Include the code of `ImageDB`. Also, try changing `Base64.DEFAULT` to `Base64.NO_WRAP`.

Comment: check that your base64 for string that you save in list is full and not cut.

Comment: @KDeogharkar, how do i check if the string is full or cut? How to determine? I cant seem to read the data.

Comment: debug your app and check your string that is generated and string that is stored in listview and compare. and also use NO_WRAP as @AbdulFatir mentioned in his comment.

Comment: I tried <code>Base64.NO_WRAP</code>, still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you encode your image into a `Base64` `String`, but you never actually decode it.

For the decoding:

```
String encodedBytes = params.get("image");
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(encodedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
```

The actual flow should be something like this:

`Bitmap` -> `byte` array -> `Base64` encoded `String` -> To DB.

From DB -> `Base64` encoded `String` -> decoded `byte` array -> decoded `Bitmap`.